# Set child cmp data from a prop, then parent cmp prop updates, child cmp data does not update?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a `message` that is passed down to my child component.

```
message: {
  type: String,
  default: null,
},
```

I also want to set this `message` prop to `null` in the child component after some interaction. I can't do it, as it's a prop, so:

```
const message = ref(props.message);
```

But when `message` changes in the parent component, the child component is not updated.

Do I need to use a watcher or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, To change message from child component you can use emit.

Second, in my point of view, ref return a new proxy object, so it will be changed when you change it from parent and message was automatically updated at child parent.

For example:

Parent Component

```js
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <h2>{{ age }}</h2>
    <button @click="setNewData">Change Age</button>
  </section>
  <section>
    <user-data
      :age="age"
      @change-age="changeAge"
    ></user-data>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
const age = ref(27);

function setNewData() {
  age.value = 40;
}
</script>
```

Child component

```js
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <h2>{{ userName }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ age }}</h2>
    <button @click="changeAge">Change Age</button>
    <h2>{{ user }}</h2>
  </section>
</template>


<script setup>
import {
  defineProps,
  defineEmits,
} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  age: Number,
});

function changeAge() {
  emit('change-age', 10);
}
</script>
```

When I press button **Change Age** on Parent Component value of age is 40 and it also update on Child Component

When I press button **Change Age** on Child Component, it will emit a method with changed age value and it back to situation 1

Answer (score 0):

When makeing a `ref` from `props.message`, you are disconnecting the value binding from it's parent. Check out the [playground code](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

If you want to update the child's value to `null` in parent you can also use emit to do so. And by using `WatchEffect` can handle value changes and detects changes automatically.